# Drop columns in a data.frame with conditions R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I am trying to be lazier than ever with R and I was wondering to know if there is a chance to drop columns from a data.frame by using a condition.

For instance, let's say my data.frame has 50 columns.

I want to drop all the columns that share each other

```
mean(mydata$coli)... = mean(mydata$coln) = 0
```

How would you write this code in order to drop them all at once? Because I use to drop columns with

```
mydata2 <- subset(mydata, select = c(vari, ..., varn))
```

Obviously not interesting because of the need of manual data checking.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Something similar as @akrun using `lapply`

```
mydata <- data.frame(col1=0, col2=1:7, col3=0, col4=-3:3)
mydata[lapply(mydata, mean)!=0]

# col2
#1    1
#2    2
#3    3
#4    4
#5    5
#6    6
#7    7
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `colMeans` to get the `mean` of all the columns as a `vector`, convert that to a logical index (`!=0`) and subset the dataset.

```
mydata[colMeans(mydata)!=0]
```

Or use `Filter` with `f` as `mean`.  If the `mean` of a column is 0, it will be coerced to `FALSE` and all others as `TRUE` to filter out the columns.

```
Filter(mean, mydata)
```

#### data

```
mydata <- data.frame(col1=0, col2=1:7, col3=0, col4=-3:3)
```